# InnoSetup - how to get ride of this error keep showing while compile?

Tags: windows, nginx, windows-installer, inno-setup

I have to run the sc.exe for nginx.exe but its failing to compile if i have it as following. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong please?

[image]

```
[Run]
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "create nginx start=auto binPath={app\nginx.exe} " ; Flags: runhidden
```

or

```
[Run]
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "create nginx start=auto binPath=""{app\nginx.exe}"" " ; Flags: runhidden
```

or

```
[Run]
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "create nginx start=auto binPath=\"{app\nginx.exe}\" " ; Flags: runhidden
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiler tells you what to do. Use two consecutive `{` chars:

```
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "create nginx start=auto binPath={{app\nginx.exe}"; Flags: runhidden
```

The problem is that compiler treats everything enclosed by `{}` chars as constants in scripting sections. So when you wrote:

```
Parameters: "create nginx start=auto binPath={app\nginx.exe}"
```

the compiler took that `{app\nginx.exe}` as a constant (just like e.g. `{app}` is). And since there is no such constant, you got this error.

Comment: WOW - Excellent Guru. Thanks a lot, my english is not so good, did not understood that i need to use that way. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: One problem the compile worked but in windows service its showing a wrong/invalid path to start {app\nginx.exe} instead of C:\program files x86\stackoverflow\nginx.exe

Comment: I admit, that I wasn't thinking about what you are trying to pass to that command line. Now I see that you were trying to expand the `{app}` constant there. Use `...binPath={app}\nginx.exe` then.